# Advice on MongoDB schema design

Tags: mongodb, schema, database, nosql

I'm currently designing the db schema for an application which will use mongodb and spring-data. I'm quite new to NoSQL databases and struggeling with the following design problem:

The application will have three simple domain objects: `Users`, `Notes` and `Tags`. Users can own several Notes (1:n) and each Note is annotated using one or more Tags (n:m).

**Now my problem is**, that I can't figure out what's the best way to design the one-to-many relationship between Notes and Tags.

The main usecase will be to query the Notes of an User by annotated Tags. So my first approach was to embed the Tags inside the Notes. I could cope with the redundancy here, as I really want fast read operations and updates of Notes and/or Tags won't probably occur that often. What I also need however, is to query for the list of all tags of an User (i.e. to implement type-ahead functionality when searching for Notes by Tags).

Currently my Note documents look something like this:

```
{
   "id":"51bcf4a97aecbafaf5e79713",
   "label":"Label of the Note",
   "contents":"Contents of the Note",
   "owner":"username",
   "tags":[
      {     
         "name":"Tag1",
         "type":"default"
      },
      {     
         "name":"Tag2",
         "type":"default"
      }
   ]
}
```

**My main questions are:**

- If I go with embedding, what would be the best way to efficiently query for the list of all tags of an User (without duplicates)?
- Would it be better to use referencing over embedding in this setting? How can I then query for all Notes that are annotated with a list of certain tags? (Is this possible at all?)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to store notes as you described and additionally store all used tags in user document. Remember that data redundancy is acceptable in MongoDB and very often is the best way to go since you should design your schema for reads, not for writes.

Then on the Java side you just store tags in Set as a property of User class so you can be sure to store unique data there.